# Getting data out of an NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, ios10

I have a fetch to core data that returns a NSManagedObject like so

```
let results = try context.fetch(data);
let resultset = results as! [NSManagedObject];
```

I have a string array created like so:

```
var db: [String] = [];
```

My core data has a column called blogs.

How do I get that entire column into my db variable?

Blogs column is a string.

New to core data too.

Comment: Did you try to read documentation?

Comment: confusing question - are you asking how to get ANY data out of the managed object, or how to get ALL of blogs extracted?  For the second option, I think you just have to iterate through the whole resultset, and add entries to db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `map` function

```
let results = try context.fetch(data) as! [NSManagedObject]
db = results.map { $0.value(forKey: "blogs") as! String }
```

or – preferable – if your are using `NSManagedObject` subclass and generic entity

```
let results = try context.fetch(data)
db = results.map { $0.blogs }
```

And remove the semicolons in your code by the way...